# JSON library , avoid number scientific notation format without converting to string

Tags: java, json, xml

I am using the following code

`String xml= "my xml"; JSONObject obj = XML.toJSONObject(xml)`

to convert an xml string into json object.

The problem is when I use the method `XML.toJSONObject(string);` some numbers of the resulting json are represented with the scientific notation format like this :

**{"ResponseObject": {"list":    [
{
"firstNumber": 14584094000106,
"secondNumber": 1.96400002E7,
"thirdNumber": 3437000.01,
"string": "test",
"boolean": true
} ] } }**

And when I use `XML.toJSONObject(string,keepStrings);` all the json fields will be kept as string :  **{"ResponseObject": {"list":    [
{
"firstNumber": "14584094000106",
"secondNumber": "19640000.2",
"thirdNumber": "3437000.01",
"string": "test",
"boolean": "true"
} ] } }**

Is there a way to avoid number scientific notation format without converting to string and without abandoning the usage of json library ?

desired result :
**{"ResponseObject": {"list":    [
{
"firstNumber": 14584094000106,
"secondNumber": 19640000.2,
"thirdNumber": 3437000.01,
"string": "test",
"boolean": true
} ] } }**

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed by migrating to the last version released of the library "json-20201115"